# How can I solve 'this'?

Tags: javascript, this, bind

```js
target = 'global honey';

const test = () => {
    console.log(this.target); // global honey
}

const object = {
    target: 'local honey',
    action: test
}

object.action();
```

The output from this code is undefined. I want to output global honey, but can't I use bind to solve this problem?

```js
target = "global honey";

const test = () => {
  console.log(this.target); // global honey
};

const object = {
  target: "local honey",
  action: test,
};

object.action.bind(object);
```

When I run this code, no value is output.

Comment: `bind` has no effect on arrow functions, and `bind` doesn't run the function you call it on, but returns a bound function (which your code doesn't use). But I am confused... you say you want to output "global honey", so why would you want to do `bind(object)`? Did you make a mistake, and actually want to output "local honey"?

Comment: as @trincot hinted at, replace ```const test = () => {``` with ```const test = function() {``` and try again :)

Comment: The first example logs **global honey**. If by *output* you mean the return value of `object.action()`, that is `undefined` because the `test` function doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 1):

> When I run this code, no value is output.

It looks like you assume that `.bind()` will run your function, but it doesn't. It just returns a new function.

Secondly, `bind` has no effect on arrow functions, so it is useless to call it here.

> I want to output global honey

Then what is the purpose of "local honey" in your code? I will assume that you actually want to output "local honey"...

In that case you don't need bind, but should make `test` a `function`, so that it will initialise `this` to the object it is called on, and not to the `this` in its lexical context (which is `globalThis` in your code).

So:

```js
var target = 'global honey';

function test() {
    console.log(this.target); // local honey
}

const object = {
    target: 'local honey',
    action: test
}

object.action();
```